# Server Sent Events with vue.js Nginx in Docker

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, server-sent-events

I have a NodeJS API server, serving some data to clients over Server Sent Events (SSE).
On the client side is a Vue.js app that connects via `EventSource`.

When running both server and client on local environment, the client connects fine, and receives the SSE events.

For production, both server and client run inside Docker containers. The server simply starts as a node server in the container. For the client, it uses a two-stage Docker build, and uses Nginx to serve the app.

All client routes work 100%.

But, when opening the client route that connects to the SSE endpoint, the connection remains in `(pending)` on the browser dev tools network tab.

I suspect this has something to do with the Nginx config.

Is there a specific client config that I am missing?

The existing `nginx.conf`:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        off;
    keepalive_timeout  60;
    gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Existing `default.conf` looks like:

```
server {
  location / {
    root /;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```